# Using ServiceWorker in Cordova

Tags: android, cordova, service-worker

We have been happily developing our app using Service Workers because of the ease of building an offline app.

It's registered in the usual way:

```
navigator.serviceWorker.register( "./worker.js" ).then( function () {
  console.log( "woohoo!" );
}, function ( err ) {
  console.log( "oh noes", err );
});
```

And it is actually quite simple:

```
self.addEventListener( "install", function () {
    console.log( "yay" );
});
```

It works fine while developing in the desktop browser, behind a web server.

But is there a way to use it while in Cordova/Crosswalk, as they use the `file` protocol?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29895387/service-workers-and-ios

Comment: Thank you @JeffPosnick, but it was my fault - I forgot to add that this is for Android.

Comment: @gustavohenke so, what is the final answer? My guess is that cordova supports it out-of-the-box for android, and needs a plugin for ios?

Comment: I haven't developed Cordova apps since the time of this question. The Android API is there, but to add a SW, you must actually be on a HTTPS host. Because iOS needed a plugin to add this functionality, you're able to overcome this limitation.