# Using service workers with Cordova on iOS and external resources

Tags: ios, cordova, cordova-plugins, service-worker

I am aware of [the Service Workers and iOS question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29895387/service-workers-and-ios). This is not a duplicate, and some fresh answers would be welcome because the only answer there is just "this thing exists" without any indications on how to use it.

My use case for this plugin is as a polyfill. I would have an *extremely simple* Cordova app that simply loads my real app located at some URL - that webapp would use service workers to cache resources offline, do background sync if available, and so on. This only applies to iOS as I *know* service workers are supported on Chrome for Android.

The question is twofold: Is this a viable use case? And if so, how would I set up my Cordova app so that it works as I intend?