# Existing now a solution to create Notification Push/Receive in PWA for iOS safari?

Tags: ios, push-notification, progressive-web-apps

Hye!

Is there any solution to receive all notification via ServiceWorker & emit a notification in progressive Web App with iOS safari?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Service workers and iOS / Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29895387/service-workers-and-ios-safari)

Answer (score 0):

Service workers are not (yet) supported in iOS.  Visit this [site](https://webkit.org/status/#?search=service) every now and then just to see if Apple will ever support it.  Keeping fingers crossed

**EDIT**
Service workers are now *In Development*!  Exciting times!